# Connect to Postgres using Docker

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm kinda lost. I have a postgres database running in a docker container which I started using docker compose. Everything was working fine until recently I get an error saying

`FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I connected to the database using spring - jdbc.

application.properties

```
## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM library/postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD password
ENV POSTGRES_DB mydb
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
    database:
        build: ./postgres
        ports: 
            - "5432:5432"
        restart: unless-stopped
```

I can connect to the database using pgAdmin, however I cant connect using my spring-application or SQuirreL.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"(pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:525)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.lambda$execute$0(OpenConnectionCommand.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I kinda fixed it. I changed the username and the password just because I was desperate. It worked and now I am even more confuse than before

Answer (score 0):

I could connect to Postgresql Database inside Docker container. I suppose you should write database name inside docker-compose file. Here mine is **db** inside docker-compose. In addition I wrote all postgres confs inside compose file instead of Dockerfile. Then I wrote *jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/abdu* like this. Here instead of localhost I wrote db name like in compose file. And also make sure you write database username and password correctly. Hope it helps.

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/abdu
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD jarfolder/docker-time-zona.jar docker-time-zona.jar
EXPOSE 8086
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/docker-time-zona.jar"]
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
  db:
    restart: always
    container_name: docker-postgresql
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=abdu
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: unfortunately this did nothing. The curious part is that this has been working for a month or so. I checked my git commits and can't see any change that could affected the database.